# Windows 10 Active Directory Administrative Center to manage untrusted domain

Tags: active-directory, command-line-interface, windows-10, runas

In a windows 7 environment, all the rsat tools are able to manage untrusted domains by using the runas /netonly command to launch said tools and connect to the domain.

In windows 10 however, the Administrative Center crashes when it is launched by this command. I haven't been able to find a solution as of yet. Event viewer points to .Net being the issue but I am not 100% certain

I have attempted the following ways to launch the administrative center and each time the same results happen.

```
    runas /netonly /user:domain\username dsac.exe

    runas /netonly /user:domain\username "dsac.exe /server=servername.fqdn"

    runas /netonly /user:domain\username ServerManager.exe
    Launch Administrative Center from Server Manager.

    runas /netonly /user:domain\username cmd.exe
    From new command line window run dsac.exe
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to launch this specific tool to manage an untrusted domain?